# show binary string in form of bits in php

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have this code:

```
$a = pack('N',0b00111010000011110101011100100010);

$start = strlen($a)*8 -1;
$str = '';
for($k = $start; $k>=0; $k--) {
    $bit = ($a >> $k) & 1;
    $str .= $bit;
}

var_dump($str);
```

output must be this:

```
00111010000011110101011100100010
```

but show me this output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

what is wrong in this code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code to this and my problem solved:

```
$a = pack('N',0b00111010000011110101011100100010);

$str = '';
for($j=0;$j<strlen($a); $j++) {
    $byte = substr($a, $j, 1);
    $num = ord($byte);
    for($k=7; $k>=0; $k--) {
        $bit = ($num >> $k) & 1;
        $str .= $bit;

    }

}
var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo.

```
$a = pack('N',0b00111010000011110101011100100010);
               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to shift the bit you're reading instead of the data byte, same thing really.  No need to substr() a single byte, array subscript notation works

```
$a = pack('N',0b00111010000011110101011100100010);
$str = '';
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($a); $i++) {
    $byte = ord($a[$i]);
    $mask = 0x80;
    while ($mask > 0) {
        $str .= ($byte & $mask) ? '1' : '0';
    }
}

echo "$str\n";
```

Edit: fixed typos, now runs

Comment: your code execution time is very long. in my browser its time was infinite and finaly finished with overflow memory size !! but execution time of my solution is about 1 second.

Comment: oops, had two bugs in there.  try now.  Don't know why it would not have exited, though, on my system it immediately errored out.